# nanoGallery display bug

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, nanogallery

I'm building a simple static website with Bootstrap 4 for an organization.
I have a Gallery page, using the JQuery library 'nanoGallery' which is pulling albums from Flickr.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3,
JQuery 3.3.1
nanoGallery 5.10.3 (otherwise version 1 of nanoGallery)

The Problem I'm having is that when you select an Album, the images sit over the top of the Gallery name (the Gallery name for navigation).  This image pretty much displays the issue:
[image]

And here's my jquery code for it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nanoGallery1").nanoGallery({
            userID:'182126395@N08',kind:'flickr',thumbnailWidth:'auto',thumbnailHeight:180,  //110,
            thumbnailGutterWidth: 10,
            thumbnailGutterHeight: 20,
            maxItemsPerLine: 4,
            theme: 'light',
            viewerDisplayLogo:true,
            locationHash:false,
            thumbnailLabel:{ display:false}, 
            thumbnailLazyLoad:true,
            colorScheme:'light',
            level1: { thumbnailWidth: 200, thumbnailHeight: 120 }
            });
      });
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the layout?

Comment: Can you provide html, css or maybe a small piece of functional code?

Comment: The only HTML used for it is this: `<div id="nanoGallery1"></div>`.    
All the CSS is contained within the nanoGallery CSS files, which i havent modified.

I'm guessing your not familiar with nanoGallery
https://nanogallery.brisbois.fr/

Comment: No, I'm not, but it looks like a positioning problem, so I wanted to know in which content the block and possible css that is being applied to it. Is there any error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual problem was that my main CSS for the site has a class called "Separator", while it also turns out the JQuery nanoGallery library also has a class by the same name - and nanoGallery was loading the class from my main CSS, instead of from its own CSS.

So after going thru and renaming a class, and changing all its references - it works fine.

Here's an image of how it should look, when its working fine.  I actually produced this image in debugging the issue - via not loading the CSS for the main site.

[image]